# How to add veth interfaces in dpdk

Tags: dpdk

I need to create a veth device for the slowpath for control packets.

What I tried till now:
I have created veth interfaces using below command

**sudo ip link add veth1-2 type veth peer name veth2-1**

when I use command sudo dpdk-devbind.py --bind=igb_uio veth1-2 to add veth into dpdk.

It gives me an error that "Unknown device: veth2-1

Is there any way we can add veth interfaces in dpdk ?

Comment: correction to the above steps as `there are no bind to vfio-pci or igb-uio or uio-pci-generic for virtual interface`. Hence the step used for binding is incorrect. second, `is your intention to use veth packet into DPDK application?`, if yes let me know I can share the answer.

Comment: Any updates from your end @krishnabansal

Comment: requesting to update if the intention is to `use veth interface created from linux in DPDK applicartiion and not TAP, KNI, or TUN`

Comment: @VipinVarghese I need to use vpp with DPDK plugin and I need to use one vpp interfaces as veth interface and this veth interface should be binded to dpdk.
Secondly the hurdle here is how I can use veth device ( vdev) as a part of vpp conf which will be input param to rte_eal init.

Comment: based on the request, current option is use pcap with the veth interface as DPDK PMD. But since you are using VPP my recommendation is always to explore VPP to create VPP as it does not have the overhead for PCAP plugin + DPDK PMD to RX or TX packets. Happy to update as answer if it clear things for you

Comment: let me know if you need a sync up, if not please update via comment I can update the answer to clarify your requirement thus help others

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "dpdk-solution", then what you'll want to look at is KNI: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/kernel_nic_interface.html

From their docs:
The DPDK Kernel NIC Interface (KNI) allows userspace applications access to the Linux* control plane.

> The benefits of using the DPDK KNI are:
>
> - Faster than existing Linux TUN/TAP interfaces (by eliminating system
>   calls and copy_to_user()/copy_from_user() operations.
> - Allows management of DPDK ports using standard Linux net tools such as
>   ethtool, ifconfig and tcpdump.
> - Allows an interface with the kernel network stack.

If your fine using a non-dpdk solution, then a TUN/TAP device is a typical way to interface with the networking stack. Your application would receive packets on the dpdk-controlled nic, and if it is a control packet you would simply forward it on to the TUN/TAP device (or KNI if using DPDK's version of TUN/TAP). Similarly for the other direction, if the TUN/TAP/KNI device receives a packet from the networking stack, you would simply send it out the DPDK physical nic.

Comment: From the dpdk page:

> KNI is deprecated and will be removed in future. See ABI and API Deprecation.